# What is the expectation of copula function?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, copula

Let's say $X=(X_1,X_2)'$, where $X\in \mathbb{R}^2$. What is the expectation of the copula function $C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))$ - i.e. $\mathbb{E}_X\left[C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))\right]$?

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate of the later question, since that has an answer.